# How do I capture .NET CLR memory performance counters for 64-bit programs?

Tags: .net, azure, clr, azure-web-roles, performancecounter

I'm trying to add `\.NET CLR Jit(*)\% Time in Jit` and other similar counters to be gathered by  Windows Azure Diagnostics in my Azure web role. I added them to the list using

```
DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration.PerformanceCounters.DataSources.Add()
```

but they are not being gathered (other counters such as CPU consumption are meanwhile being gathered). I noticed that if I run `typeperf.exe` from `System32` folder those counters are not listed but if I instead run `typeperf.exe` from `SysWow64` folder they are listed. So I guess they are somehow only gathered for 32-bit programs and since my code runs in 64-bit processes they are not gathered for my code.

What am I doing wrong? How do I have those counters gathered?